# how to create a function to output a lying-down hourglass by entering the size of the array

Tags: arrays, c

How do I make a function to output a lying hourglass rather than a set hourglass by receiving an array?

I know how to implement a vertical hourglass.

When I received a number of five,

```
1        13
2 6   10 14
3 7 9 11 15
4 8   12 16
5        17
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need it to be generic for any numbers of rows but just for this case, so 1 foor loop would defenitly will be enough.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
            if (i == 0 || i == 4) //1st and 5th rows
                printf("%d        %d\n", i + 1, i + 13);
            else if(i == 1 || i == 3)//2nd and 4th rows
                printf("%d %d   %d %d\n", i + 1, i + 5, i + 9, i + 13);
            else
                printf("3 7 9 11 15\n");//3rd row
    }
```

if you'll like to have it generic and depends on user's input for rows number - just add another for loop and calculate the number of blanks you need and which number to print depends on the number of iteration.